# Custom Page Post Query Template

Tags: php, wordpress

**Goal:** Create Wordpress page template so that my custom page post (blog) looks like my news posts.

At the moment it looks like this: http://freelifecc.com/blog/.

Has no real formatting or blog structure post to post.  I would like it to look similar to this: http://freelifecc.com/blog-posts/the-best-defense-money-cant-buy/ except it display multiple posts.

Note: News is used in the template I'm using as the default blog posts. It's woven into the entire wordpress template so I'd rather not change that.

At the moment I'm using Custom Post Type UI to create a new post type (blog) and linking it on a page using plugin: Query Wrangler and plugin: Widgets on Page.

What do I need to do and how can I accomplish it?

Comment: You need to just create one single page for your custom post type so it will automatically reflect on this single post.

Comment: I guess I'm asking how to do that?  I've created a page (/blog) and used the shortcode to show the query but it's not formatted.